# Implementation of redquerybuilder in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redquerybuilder

[image]
I am implementing [redquerybuilder](http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/) in my project.

I have implemented up to UI level, But I am not getting how to fetch records from database and convert it into it's special JSON format.
When we click on 'Search' button, the ajax request is trigger to search page.

What happening when ajax request goes to search page, is it php page or page which content JSON format data array.

If search page is php page, so do we need to execute sql every time and return result set in JSON format.

Why I am not getting records when we click on search button?

**Edited question**
Attached browser's screenshot.
My question is when I click on Search button it is sending ajax request to 'search'.
Is that search page is .php page or not!!
What happen on search page, is it fetching records from database on every request or store predefine JSON!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am not getting how to fetch records when we click on search button.

Comment: Have you looked at the working example up on http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/ ? The demo uses http://flexigrid.info/ to display results (not part of redquerybuilder) you need to supply data in a format it likes (or use someother display).

Comment: @salk31 please read edit section, sorry for my english

Comment: In the demo that request is handled by a servlet https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/blob/master/redquerybuilder-jdbcsample/src/main/java/com/redspr/redquerybuilder/sample/SearchServlet.java  This is not a standard part of RedQueryBuilder. You need to write something for your database. So you can use PHP or anything you like on the server side. If you do come up with some PHP it might be good to add it to github for people to re-use?

Comment: @salk31 Thanks for your instant reply, Ok I got it what I have to do and very soon I will push the changes. Thanks once again.